# Pass multiple index parameters (from a list) to Pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a list of parameters that I want use as parameters in pandas.pivot_table:

```
rows = ["1", "2", r'"3","4"']

for i in rows:
   table = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna(0),index=[i], values=["X", "Y"], aggfunc=[np.sum], fill_value=0, margins="True", margins_name="Tot.")
```

But if I launch the code everything go well until the third element of the list.

`KeyError: "'3','4'"`

If I manually launch this

`table = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna(0),index=["3","4"], values=["X", "Y"], aggfunc=[np.sum], fill_value=0, margins="True", margins_name="Tot.")`

it works.

How I can pass the third element format to the function without getting error?

I've tried to write the multi-element in other ways, without success:

```
rows = ["1", "2", ["3","4"]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is `print (df.index.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael: it is a long list of number, the indexes of `df`

Answer (score 0):

Schoolboy error.

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna(0),index=[i], values=["X", "Y"], aggfunc=[np.sum], fill_value=0, margins="True", margins_name="Tot.")
```

expects a single value `i` to be passed as an element of a list (`[i]`).

So the correct way is this:

```
rows = ["1", "2", ["3","4"]]

for i in rows:
   table = pd.pivot_table(df.fillna(0),index=i, values=["X", "Y"], aggfunc=[np.sum], fill_value=0, margins="True", margins_name="Tot.")
```